# Due to lack of or due to a lack of

Tags: phrases

They abandoned the project due to lack of mobilisation.

They abandoned the project due to *a* lack of mobilisation.

Do you need the article here?

Comment: I need it. I'm not sure whether all native English speakers need it, though.

Comment: Both versions are used. Context sometimes **requires** the article for a subtle or significant difference in meaning.

Comment: Of course, not: http://www.csueastbay.edu/class/departments/theatre/theatre-archive/files/images/1970s/1972/1972-Due-To-A-Lack%20Of%20Interest-Tomorrow-Has-Been-Cancelled.jpg

Comment: *Walsall Domestic Violence Forum closes due to a lack of funding* http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-birmingham-36213847  ;  "The number of deaths due to a lack of coverage averaged three per hour and that the issue plagued every state." *Facts on Deaths Due to Lack of Health Insurance in US* http://obamacarefacts.com/facts-on-deaths-due-to-lack-of-health-insurance-in-us/

Answer (score 1):

I would say, "They abandoned the project, because of a lack of mobilisation," and use "due to" only when "due to whatever" acts as an adjective. Thus, "The number of deaths *due to* a lack of coverage..." is fine, but "a number of people died, *because of* a lack of coverage." Once you make this change, it is evident that the article, a, is required. Nowadays this is a matter of style, but if you look up "due to" in Fowler, I think you will find that Fowler considered it a rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can just say:

They abandoned the project, as they lacked mobilization.

Otherwise, I don't think you need the "a" in your sentence.

Comment: This rephrases the sentence but doesn't answer the question.